# Как вывести в datagriedview данные из базы?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, datagridview

Здравствуйте подскажите как можно вывести из базы в Datagriedview, я сделал вот так, но у меня выводится только 1 строка таким образом, а мне нужно чтобы автоматически выводились с таким видом все найденные записи, я попробовал по-другому сделать, но не получилось(

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
       string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-3FE5J7L;Initial Catalog=Shop;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Datareg FROM Dog INNER JOIN Shop on Dog.id = Shop.Dog_id Inner join Prod on Shop.prod_id = Prod.id Where Dog.id = @id", con);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdr);

        con.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 317;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = $"\nМагазин: " + (dt.Rows[i][0]) + "\n                                 Менеджер: " + (dt.Rows[i][1]) + " \n";
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: `Where Dog.id = @id` - вы сами задали условие. Айди уникальный? Значит находится только одна запись.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Здравствуйте, в таблицу выводятся все магазины и даты по нужному id, например id=3, то выводит 2 магазина, но только 1 магазин выводится вот так $"\nМагазин: " + (dt.Rows[Ctrw][0]) + "\n                                 Дата: " + (dt.Rows[Ctrw][1]) + " \n" , но как можно сделать так чтобы вывелся и 2 магазин в таком же формате?

Comment: `Rows[0].Cells[0]` - ну вы же к одной-единственной ячейке применяете форматирование. Примените ко всем! PS: делать это нужно в событии [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  а ну я поэтому вопрос и задал как можно применить ко всем?

Comment: Циклом пройтись по всем строкам. Но правильнее использовать CellFormatting.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, посмотрите пожалуйста на код я его изменил, но при запуске приложения таблица вообще не заполняется, я CellFormatting ни разу не использовал, возможно не правильно что-то сделал с ним

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не стану касаться ошибок при работе с базой данных, скажу лишь о коде, работающем с DataGridView.

---

`if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)` - эта проверка лишняя, т. к. если данных нет, то тело цикла и так не будет выполнено.

---

`for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)` - везде в коде у вас dataGridView**1**, а здесь - dataGridView**2**. И вы сразу бежите на форум: "ни работаит!" Просто внимательно проверяйте свой собственный код на наличие опечаток.

---

```
int Ctrw = dt.Rows.Count;
Ctrw = 0;
```

Смысл этого куска кода? Присвоили в переменную `Ctrw` некое значение и тут же затёрли его значением `0`.
Кстати, что означает `Ctrw`? В английском языке нет такого слова. Давайте нормальные имена всем своим переменным. Впрочем, эта переменная вовсе не нужна.

---

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = ... dt.Rows[Ctrw][0] ... dt.Rows[Ctrw][1]) ...;
```

Вот смотрите: `dataGridView1.Rows[i]` - здесь совершенно логично используется `i` - номер строки. Так почему вы здесь его не используете: `dt.Rows[Ctrw]`? Замените на `dt.Rows[i]`.

---

Если вы итерируете строки датагрида, то нужно исключить его последнюю строку (пустую):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) // обратите внимание на - 1
```

Или можно итерироваться по строкам дататейбла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
```

---

```
$"\nМагазин: " + (dt.Rows[Ctrw][0]) + "\n                                 Дата: " + (dt.Rows[Ctrw][1]) + " \n"
```

Вы вроде как собрались использовать интерполированную строку: поставили значок `$`. Но далее собираете строку конкатенацией.
И к чему множество пробелов? Судя по символу `\n`, вы хотите вывод в две строки.

По-моему, это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
$"Магазин: {dt.Rows[i][0]}\nДата: {dt.Rows[i][1]}"
```

Кстати, чтобы текст в ячейке выводился в несколько строк, нужно задать:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

---

**Итоговый код:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = $"Магазин: {dt.Rows[i][0]}\nДата: {dt.Rows[i][1]}";
}
```

---

Вместо явного задания ширины колонки: `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 317;` на мой взгляд лучше использовать автоматическое задание размеров:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

---

---

Форматирование вывода в датагриде следует делать в событии [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=net-5.0).

В нём пишем:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        e.Value = $"Магазин: {dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][0]}\nДата: {dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][1]}";
    }
}
```

У вас `DataTable` сделан локальной переменной. Если его сделать *полем* класса (формы):

```
private DataTable dt;
```

то код упростится:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        e.Value = $"Магазин: {dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][0]}\nДата: {dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][1]}";
    }
}
```